# How to cluster spacy vectors (word embedding) into groups using Annoy or other similar algorithms

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, nearest-neighbor, annoy

I have a list of words whose vector embeddings I got by using spacy's pre trained model *en_core_web_lg*.

My questions are two fold

Can these word vectors be fed into Annoy like algorithm?
Can I get say 20 groups, each group containing around 100 words?

I would be grateful for any resources/code.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @chefhose Well I have tried this illustration [https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/auto_examples/tutorials/run_annoy.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-tutorials-run-annoy-py] but the point is I know how to get similar words. I want to know how to cluster similar words into 1 group.